# Filter ARP packets with specific "Who has" and "Tell" IP

Tags: wireshark

Here is an ARP packet:

```
192.168.1.3     ARP 62  Who has 192.168.1.1? Tell 192.168.1.2
```

How to display only ARP packets with

1) specific "Who has" IP (`192.168.1.1` here)?
2) specific "Tell" IP (`192.168.1.2` here)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wireshark ARP filter reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/a/arp.html)

1. To filter "Who has" you need `( arp.dst.proto_ipv4 == 192.168.1.1 ) && ( arp.opcode==1 )`
2. To find "Tell" you need `( arp.src.proto_ipv4 == 192.168.1.2 ) && ( arp.opcode==1 )`